# How to show div element next to button in reactJS table

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

How to show div element next to button in reactJS table

I am using a table component and where I need to show some option in small window which can get close once I click outside.

options :

[image: Options]

Action button in table.  :

[image: Button]

Now I am able to close the window but the positioning is very difficult to place next to button.

Here is my table code.

Note : Table is some common component.

```
<Table   
  className="table-hover"
    headers={MyAPi.getListHeaders()}
    data={this.state.data}
    dataKey=“I”d
    dataValue=“value”
    actionIcon="gear"
    action={( rowIndex: any, row: any, id: string,value: string ) => {
        if (rowIndex === this.state.rowIndex) {
            this.setState({
                isOpen: false,
                rowIndex: -1,
                eventY: -680
            });
            return;
        }
        this.setState({
            isOpen: true,
            items: this.state.items,
            rowIndex: rowIndex,
            eventY: -680 + rowIndex * 40
        });
        
    }}
    
></Table>

{this.state.isOpen ? (
    <div
        style={{
            width: "110px",
            height: "120px",
            transform: "translateX(590%) translateY(" + this.state.eventY + "%)",
            backgroundColor: "#f3f4f5",
            border: "1px solid #C4C8CF"
        }}
    >
        <div style={{ listStyleType: "none" }}>
            {this.state.dropdownItems.map((item: any, index: number) => {
                return (
                    <li
                        style={{
                            color: "#444444",
                            paddingTop: "10px",
                            paddingLeft: "15px",
                            textAlign: "left",
                            fontSize: "14px",
                            cursor: "pointer"
                        }}
                        key={item}
                        onClick={(e) => {
                            this.handleClick(e);
                        }}
                    >
                        {item}
                    </li>
                );
            }, this)}
        </div>
    </div>
) : (
    <></>
)}
```

Here the problem is happening while calculation y element which is like vary for each record and I need to maintain in state. So any help how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

CSS can fix this , Make the `Table cell > position >> relative` and `Dialog > position >> absolute`, this serves as Parent for `Dialog` you render

```
<TableCell
                style={{
                  position: "relative"
                }}
                align="right"
              >
                <Settings
                  clickedName={clickedName}
                  handleSet={handleSet}
                  name={row.name}
                  dropdownItems={dropdownItems}
                />
              </TableCell>
```

Action button

```
function Settings({
  ...props
}) {
  return (
    <IconButton onClick={(e) => handleSet(name)}>
      <SettingsIcon />
      {clickedName === name && (
        <Dialog isOpen={true}  dropdownItems={dropdownItems} />
      )}
    </IconButton>
  );
}
```

Comment: what is TableCell here ?

Comment: Think it as a ```<td>``` where info reside.

Comment: You could have used any third party componets like ```MUI``` .